# DocuSign "invalid_grant" on posting jwtToken

Tags: oauth, jwt, docusignapi

I'm trying to achieve "Service Integration Authentication" following the steps here [docusign docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html) and it's doing fine until **Requesting the Access Token**, where you send the jwt token (which is well formed)

**I'm always getting "invalid_grant"**, and according to that doc, is because some of the claims are invalid. Is there another cause for that error?
All the claims looks good

C#:

```
//request access token
        var client3 = new RestClient("https://" + _host);
        var request3 = new RestRequest("/oauth/token", Method.POST);
        request3.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request3.AddParameter("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");

        var headers = new[]
        {
            new Claim("alg", "RS256"),
            new Claim("typ", "JWT"),
        }.ToList();

        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim("iss", _integrationKey), //<-- integration key
            new Claim("sub", OAuthGrant.Sub), //<-- returned from /oauth/userinfo (OK)
            new Claim("iat", ToUnixTime(DateTime.Now).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
            new Claim("exp", ToUnixTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
            new Claim("aud", _host), //<-- "account-d.docusign.com"
            new Claim("scope", "signature"),
        }.ToList();

        //build jwt from private key. token decodes just fine from https://jwt.io/
        var jwtToken = CreateToken(claims, headers, "private-key.pem", Server.MapPath("/"));
        request3.AddParameter("assertion", jwtToken);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("jwtToken:" + jwtToken);

        var response = client3.Execute<OAuthToken>(request3);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("response content:" + response.Content); //<-- getting "invalid_grant"

        return response.Data;
```

The jwt token was validated using https://jwt.io/ and decodes just fine.
Is **docusign demo sandbox**

Thanks in advance
daniel

Comment: Are you using User Consent or Admin Consent? If Admin Consent then you need to claim email domain first in DocuSign. If User Consent, then you need to get consent from the user via Authorization Code Grant URL.

Comment: Hi Amit, yes I'm using User Consent, from the callback I get the **access token** and with it, I call the **/oauth/userinfo** to get the "Sub". I believe I'm missing something in the admin console

Comment: will request3.AddParameter() method add "grant_type" and "assertion" in the body of the request while generating access token?

Comment: Yes Sir, POST data travels in the body and is URI encoded. Just in case I've tried POSTing as querystring with no luck either. I've checked this behaviour with Fiddler

Comment: It should not go in URL, it should be in Body only. Can you create assertion in jwt.io website, then use Postman to generate "AccessToken", just to see if everything is correctly configure in DS Admin' Integrator Key and you correctly got the User consent.

Comment: Yeah, postman gives me good data:
`
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0e......(blah blah)......DQ",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJ0eXAi....(blah blah)...j8y4A",
    "expires_in": 28800
}
`

Should I start from scratch and tried a different integration key?

Comment: No that means something is wrong in your code while creating assertion. Now generate assertion in your code and try to use that assertion in the Postman. I know sometimes assertion is wrong because of the iat and exp.

Comment: Same error "invalid_grant", I'm using iat=now, exp=(now+1hour), both in unix (secs from 1970) could that be the problem? Is definitely in the assertion portion of the code. I'm encoding the JSON using the private key provided by the DS Admin.

Comment: I don't know what library your code is using, It should be 10 digits value like, 1517505945. You need to debug more in detail how wrong assertion is getting created and how you can fix it, or do you need to change library.You can check DS SDK as well - ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow method in [DS SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/ApiClient.cs)

Comment: What's the CreateToken method. From a library? Which one? Or is it your own code?

Comment: Hi guys, I finally used the sdk an examples provided by DS. Doing some debug and comparing requests I noticed the JWT was completely different (using library JOSE in C#), so the problem was there. Thanks for the help, I'm sticking to git's code from now.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is the library which you are using is generating wrong assertion for you. You can check DS SDK as well - ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow method in [DS SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/ApiClient.cs), it will help you in generating the Assertion in correct way as expected by DS APIs.